# HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden. Any ways to bypass?

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, google-colaboratory, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to automate web scraping on this site, which generally works once before it gives me HTTP Error 403. I have tried changing the user agent as suggested in similar questions here but to no avail. Initially I was planning on scraping 100+ results but I changed it to only 19 results but I'm still blocked. Would there be any ways to by pass the site blocking authorization? Any help is appreciated!

**Code**

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import requests
from itertools import cycle
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

journal_url = []

pagesToScrape = 1

for i in range(1,pagesToScrape+1):

  search_url = f"https://jamanetwork.com/searchresults?q=vegan&exPrm_qqq=%7bDEFAULT_BOOST_FUNCTION%7d%22vegan%22&exPrm_hl.q=vegan&page={i}"
  req = Request(search_url , headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
  webpage = urlopen(req).read()
  soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")
  
  for i in soup.find_all('h3', attrs={'class':'article--title at-sr-item-title-link'}):
    journal_url.append(i.a['href'])

date = []

for journal in journal_url:
  journal_req = Request(journal , headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
  journal_webpage = urlopen(journal_req).read()
  journal_soup = BeautifulSoup(journal_webpage, "html.parser")  

  try:
    title = journal_soup.find('h1', attrs={'class':'meta-article-title '}).get_text() #finds journal's title
  except AttributeError:
    continue

  try:
    accept = journal_soup.find("strong", text="Accepted for Publication:").next_sibling.strip(" .") #finds journal accepted for publication date
  except AttributeError:
    continue
  except:
    accept = journal_soup.find("strong", text="Submitted for Publication:").next_sibling.strip(" ;")

  try:
    accept = datetime.strptime(accept, '%B %d, %Y') #convert str to datetime
  except ValueError:
    continue
  
  try:
    publish = journal_soup.find("strong", text="Published Online:").next_sibling.strip(". doi:") #finds journal's online publishing date
  except AttributeError:
    continue

  try:
    publish = datetime.strptime(accept, '%B %d, %Y') #convert str to datetime
  except ValueError:
    continue

  timeBetweenPublish = publish - accept

  date.append([title, accept, publish, timeBetweenPublish]) #adds variables into list

  print(title)
  df = pd.DataFrame(date, columns=['Title', 'Accepted for Publication Date', 'Published Online Date', 'Time Between Accepted Date and Published Date'])
  df.to_csv('date.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a slightly longer user agent. The page probably checks for additional information not included in the short form.

```py
import requests

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.5026.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/103.0.1254.0"

page = 1

url = f"https://jamanetwork.com/searchresults?q=vegan&exPrm_qqq=%7bDEFAULT_BOOST_FUNCTION%7d%22vegan%22&exPrm_hl.q=vegan&page={i}"

page = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": user_agent})

print(page.status_code)
```

You can find your user agent at https://ifconfig.me/

Comment: Appreciate it! Following your advice, I used longer user agents based on this article (https://www.zenrows.com/blog/user-agent-web-scraping#why-is-a-user-agent-important-for-web-scraping). But I'm still having the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: @persimmons Try copying all the headers from the dev tools network tab from the browser into the code. Use requests module.

Comment: @persimmons Can you please give me a feedback? Works the copying headers?